# Java main process suspended because of exceptions thrown from threads

Tags: java, multithreading

The main process:

```
            int cpus = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cpus);
            List<Callable<Object>> todo = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>(lines.size());
            for (int r = 0; r < lines.size(); r++) {
                String filename = r + 1 + "";
                todo.add(Executors.callable(new AppConsole(filename, lines.get(r))));
            }
            List<Future<Object>> answers = executor.invokeAll(todo);
```

The AppConsole class implements Runnable and the overriden run method is as follows:

```
public void run() {
  try{



  } catch (SecurityException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (output != null) {
                output.close();
            }
        }
  }
```

}

The main process is suspended and cannot finish because of a connection timeout exception thrown from one of the threads. Now I can see the cpu usage drops to 0% and the memory consumption keeps at the same level when it got suspended.

Could someone please help me solve this problem? At least, help me make the main process finish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throwing an exception frees up the tasks and the main thread. The ExecutorService treats an Exception throw much like another return value and doesn't have a problem handling it.

The main thread will only block waiting for one of your tasks to complete.  I would look at the tasks/threads which are still active to see what they are doing e.g. perhaps they haven't timed out yet.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on how to see what the threads are doing?

Comment: I accidentally made the main process to finish despite the exception by explictly writing a return statement in each of the catch blocks. This evidence seems contradictory against your claim: Throwing an exception frees up the tasks.

Comment: This means you are doing something after the return which is holding up the thread.  Are you sure it is safe to close a stream which has timed-out?

Comment: You mean the problem is caused by the statement in the finally block? The finally block is the last thing being executed in the run method. I can't think of any case where the close statement in the finally block may go wrong.

Comment: There is nothing you have shown in your code which should go wrong.  But you have a problem all the same.  I suspect it is in the code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add:

```
executor.shutdown();
```

This waits when all tasks will be completed and shutdown all threads, application will exit after that.
Please see javadoc for [newFixedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/):

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating
>   off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most nThreads threads
>   will be active processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted
>   when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a
>   thread is available. If any thread terminates due to a failure during
>   execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed
>   to execute subsequent tasks. The threads in the pool will exist until
>   it is explicitly shutdown.

Comment: So if I do not explictly shut down the executor, the main process won't finish?

Comment: invokeAll already waits for all the tasks to complete, no?  From the docs for invokeAll : "Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete. Future.isDone() is true for each element of the returned list. Note that a completed task could have terminated either normally or by throwing an exception."

Comment: Yes, but threads still live. And according to javadoc: `The threads in the pool will exist until it is explicitly shutdown.`

Answer (score 0):

you could use the alternative version of invokeAll that takes an explicit timeout value :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

```
invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks,
                          long timeout,
                          TimeUnit unit)
```

this way you can force all of your tasks to timeout after, say, 30 seconds.  Then you can inspect the Futures returned to see which have completed.